# Magento2 Layout move element only for desktop view?

Tags: magento2, layout, luma-theme, custom-theme

I'm trying to adapt the Luma Theme for my needs and move some elements in layout.
I add a `default.xml` file in my Child Theme and add those lines :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <move element="minicart" destination="header.container" before="-" />
      <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

The `minicart` is now on the `header container` but is there a directive to apply these changes only for **Desktop** and **not** for **Mobile** view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML layout files do not care about platform or screen size. You'll have to use CSS and JS to get the style you're going for.

[Documentation about moving elements with JS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html)

> The `responsive.js` script implements specific responsive functions for the Blank and Luma themes.

Comment: Meaning that I should not move my block in the layout but only by CSS ?

Comment: You may still find it useful to move the element using xml so that it takes less work in css and js for your specific view. You can also consider cloning elements and then hiding/showing on the appropriate screens

Comment: Added a link to my answer